# How to deal with long PHP scripts?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a `foreach` function to import a 30mb CSV file into MySQL. This script need to run for about 2-5 minutes and I'm already using the `ob_flush`.

Now my question is:

Is there any other option to give the user an indication of the loading progress? At this point you never know when the script will be fully load.

Comment: Through Long Polling (Sending an intermittent AJAX Request to check against a Database of the current recorded progress, e.g. The Script has completed 25%, Save Milestone to DB, Wait for AJAX to read it then Update bar accordingly) or use *Websockets*.

Comment: Don't do this inside the web server process. Put it on a scheduled event (e.g. cron) or add it to a job server (e.g. Gearman).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm using a foreach function to import a 30mb CSV file into MySQL. This script need to run for about 2-5 minutes and I'm already using the ob_flush.

The best advice is not to use a `foreach` loop to import CSV into MySQL at all.... MySQL provides a built-in feature for importing CSV files which is **much** quicker.

Look up the manual page for the MySQL [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) feature.

Seriously, when I say "much quicker", I mean it -- switch your code to use `LOAD DATA INFILE`, and you won't need a progress bar.

Comment: The one caveat I would add to this is that CSV is not a standardised format, and not every file produced as a CSV file by one tool can be imported cleanly by another, let alone line up to SQL types correctly. However, you can often import the raw data into a temporary table and run UPDATE statements to fix problems with particular columns.

Comment: An other way (LOAD DATA INFILE requires FILE access) is to combine multiple INSERT into one INSERT with multiple VALUES. It could be many times faster and does not require a change in the DB.

Comment: @IMSoP - `LOAD DATA INFILE` is very flexible in terms of the ability to define the delimiters, line endings, etc. It's pretty good at handling files in odd formats, as long as the format is consistent it should cope.

Answer (score 2):

I am agree with @SuperJer, you must use AJAX.

Everyday I importing 50MB data because we have ecommerce website. We used AJAX on left side and put a loader which show "Files uploading....".

Foreach is good if you have less data, but for huge data I think its not good. Always use inbuilt methods or function.

To upload csv file you may use below syntax

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/your_csv_file.csv' INTO TABLE tablename.
```

Comment: My solution is actually quite free of AJAX.  Essentially, Javascript commands are appended to the page as the work is being completed, rather than a recurring communication with the session.

Comment: As a note, your CSV data must be absolutely correct, as incorrect data will cause all kinds of trouble.

Comment: @tadman you are right...if user pass wrong or invalid data it will throw error/warning.. or you can verify it with log file..

Answer (score 1):

One of the easier ways to do this would be to call the function that does the work at the end of the page, AFTER all the page HTML has been sent to the browser.

Assuming jQuery, make note of the element in which you want the progress indicator to appear, such as `id='progressBar'`.

Then, as you iterate through your loop, every 100 iterations or so, echo a javascript line to update that element with the new percentage:

```
echo "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $('#progressBar').html('".(int)$percentage."');
    </script>";
```

You'll want to make sure, depending on the number of iterations, to not overwhelm the browser with javascript code blocks.  Perhaps check if the percentage is divisible by 5, prior to echoing the block.

Also, if you are looping through a CSV and `INSERT`ing it line-by-line, it would be better (faster) to insert a block of them, say 500 lines per `INSERT`.  This is also easily displayed using the same method.